# Корректна ли следующая конструкция?

Tags: objective-c

```
[self setUsersWhosemMessagesaArenNotRead:[[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath] UsersWhosemMessagesaArenNotRead]];
```

Меня интересует, что происходит с объектом, который я передаю в качестве аргумента? Он освобождается после этой строчки или остается в памяти? Спасибо!

Comment: лучше на вопрос ответе, чем лайки ставить

Comment: ARC / non-ARC?

Comment: Да, я использую ARC

Answer (score 1):

Методу передается ссылка на объект аргумента. Как только методу перестанет быть нужен доступ к объекту, ARC "освободит" объект.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то после выполнения метода объекта не будет существовать в пямяти. Так?

Comment: Судя по названию метода, объект будет присвоен какой-то другой переменной (если это сеттер, то айвару объекта self). Если это так, то он (объект) будет существовать до тех пор, пока эта переменная ссылается на объект, однако если в сеттере производится копирование объекта, что врядли, то объект "будет-аргумент" будет освобожден сразу.

Comment: Не нужно особо париться над управлением памятью при использовании ARC. Используете инструмент Leaks для ловли утечек памяти и циклов удержания

Comment: У меня сейчас приложение занимает около 20 - 40 мб при использовании. Там просто осуществляется подгрузка и все такое. Хотелось бы узнать это нормально?